# Inverse of a multivariables function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What would the inverse of the following functions be?

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z)&:= (x-3y + 5z -14, x-4y+5z-3, 2x-3y+4z+1) \\
g(x,y)&:= (5x-3y-22, 2x - 2y -9)
\end{align*}

I would normally do these by using the matrix system, and by applying the Gauss-Jordan method I'd get the identity matrix and the inverse. But since I've got loose numbers with no variables, I don't know how to do this.

And how would i be able to check if the answer is right once i got it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way to deal with the loose numbers is to just bring them out as a constant.  Let me explain what I mean.  Notice that $f$ satisfies:
$$
f(x, y, z) =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 5 \\
1 & -4 & 5 \\
2 & -3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-14 \\ -3 \\ 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In other words, if $u = (x,y,z)$, we can write $f(u) = Au + u_0$, where $A$ is a matrix and $u_0$ is a constant vector.
Then the inverse of $f$ will just be
$$
f^{-1}(v) = A^{-1}(v - u_0)
$$
You can check that this is the inverse by plugging in $f(u)$ for $v$.  So you can find the inverse function if you know the inverse of the matrix, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is the inverse of $y=mx+b$? Well, we would have $y-b=mx$, and so $x=$...

Your situation is just like this, but you have $y=Ax+b$.